# How to out put the PC name that has certain process running?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I m using psexec to auto run

get.bat

---

tasklist | findstr pmill.exe >> dc-01\c$\0001.txt

---

run_get.bat

---

psexec @%1 -u administrator -p password -c "C:\get.bat"

---

pclist.txt

---

on all PCs on our network,

how can i get the result with PC name instead of only pmill.exe in the text file?
is there anyway i can do from powershell?
I need to get the pc name in result.
Hint  plz!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of psexec, try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%I in (pclist.txt) do (
    set /p q="Checking %%I... "<NUL
    ping -n 1 -w 500 %%I>NUL 2>NUL
    if !errorlevel!==1 (
        echo Offline.
    ) else (
        wmic /node:%%I /user:adminuser /password:pass process where name="pmill.exe" get csname 2>NUL | find /i "%%I" >>dc-01\c$\0001.txt
        echo Done.
    )
)
```

That'll output `%computername%` if pmill.exe is running, or nothing otherwise.

**Edit:**

If you must use `psexec` then I suggest changing the logic of your `for` loop that calls `psexec`, something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%I in (pclist.txt) do (
    set pc=%%I
    set /p q="Checking %%I... "<NUL
    ping -n 1 -w 500 %%I>NUL 2>NUL
    if !errorlevel!==1 (
        echo Offline.
    ) else (
        for /f %%z in ('psexec \\!pc! -u adminuser -p pass tasklist 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "pmill.exe"') do (
            set /p q="pmill.exe found.  "<NUL
            echo !pc!>>dc-01\c$\0001.txt
        )
        echo Done.
    )
)
```

Comment: OK, I  can try wmic, but i still have to use psexec for auto run on all PCs.

Comment: btw, what does 2>nul mean?

Comment: `2>NUL` means redirect stderr to a black hole.  `wmic` outputs newlines via stderr for no good reason.  The `2>NUL` squashes them.  In my updated `psexec` example, `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout.  See [Using command redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Try it again.  I forgot to escape the `2^>^&1` in the for loop.  I also completed the `wmic` method if you want to give that a try.  In my experience, `wmic` is much faster than `psexec`.

Comment: it is woking now, but all i got in result are %I

Comment: @Blitzcrank - Not sure why that'd be happening, but I did `enabledelayedexpansion` to hack around it.  Try again por favor.

Comment: @PatrickMeinecke there were no error msg, it just print all codes on screen without doing anything.

Comment: @blitzcrank - that's because at the time you tried it, the code I suggested was a direction, not the answer.  I didn't have output redirected to you're log file.  Please think for yourself and be prepared to tailor people's answers to your needs.